# Rails 5 Wicked-pdf open pdf in new window from a form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i created one form that saves data in two different table, based on upon button clicks, now am able to save data into two different table.

using Wicked PDF for pdf creation.

now i want when user clicks on `preview` button then i want to render same template that i render on `create` action. i am not able to open preview pdf when user clicks on preview button.

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: @invoice, :html => {:id => 'invoice-form-validation'}, url: [@payment_milestone,@invoice], local: true) do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.submit ' Preview Invoice', name: 'preview_invoice_submit', :class=>"button secondary button-margin-top fa fa-eye" %>
    <%= form.submit :class=>"button primary button-margin-top fa fa-files-o", name: 'invoice_submit'%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

invoices_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @invoices = @payment_milestone.invoices
    @invoice = Invoice.new
  end

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
      format.pdf {render template: 'invoices/services_report', pdf: "services_invoice"}
    end
  end

  def create

    invoice_model = params[:invoice_submit] ? Invoice : TempInvoice
    @invoice = invoice_model.new(invoice_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_financial_payment_milestone_invoices_path, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' } 
      else
        format.html { redirect_to project_financial_payment_milestone_invoices_path}
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commit or the form sets a parameter with the name of the submit button.
So you can test the clicked submit button and can redirect on preview:

```
def create
  invoice_model = params[:invoice_submit] ? Invoice : TempInvoice
  @invoice = invoice_model.new(invoice_params)
  
  if @invoice.save
    if params.has_key?(:preview_invoice_submit)
      redirect_to project_financial_payment_milestone_invoice_path(@invoice, format: :pdf)
    else
     redirect_to project_financial_payment_milestone_invoices_path, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.'
    end
  else
    redirect_to project_financial_payment_milestone_invoices_path
  end
end
```

(pathnames are guessed)

Comment: getting error like ```undefined method `has_key' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007fadc87767a8> Did you mean? has_key?```

Comment: I do not have a `respond_to` in the `create` action. You always POST `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not html or so. This is why you have to redirect to the show method with the propper format (i.e. pdf). Does the `show` action work with format :pdf, i.e. by GETting ...invoices/1.pdf?

Comment: this worked as i expected but i am still getting problem in line ```def set_invoice
      @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
    end``` of invoice controller when i try to view from temp model and if i do ```TempInvoice.find(params[:id])``` then i get view error in from invoice model

Comment: I can understand that, but it is an other topic. When you use different classes for the same purpose. OK what you can do is `@invoice = Invoice.find_by(id: params[:id]) || TempInvoice.find(params[:id])`. BUT: you will get problems when :id of Invoice and TempInvoice are not completely separate (i.e. an UUID). It would be better to have different actions (even better and more Rail-isch different Controller) for Invoice and TempInvoice ... or use `single table inheritence` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html to store Invoive and TempInvoice in the same table.